# Google apps script loop to toggle font size and color a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to toggle a cell value in 8 sheets of a spreadsheet basically to highlight the cell value and get the reader's attention

I have an `onEdit` function with other functions,

```
function onEdit(){
  cp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // The fucntion for hide/unhide sheets/tabs
  var sheet1 = cp.getSheetByName("1 s");
  var sheet2 = cp.getSheetByName("2 s");
  var sheet3 = cp.getSheetByName("3 s");
  var sheet4 = cp.getSheetByName("4 s");
  var sheet5 = cp.getSheetByName("5 s");
  var sheet6 = cp.getSheetByName("6 s");
  var sheet7 = cp.getSheetByName("7 s");
  var sheet8 = cp.getSheetByName("8 s");
  var Overview = cp.getSheetByName("Overview");

  var [cella, cellb, cellc, celld, celle, cellf, cellg, cellh, celli] = Overview.getRange("C6:C14").getValues().flat();
  if (cella =="Yes") { sheet1.showSheet(); } else { sheet1.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellb == "Yes") { sheet2.showSheet(); } else { sheet2.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellc == "Yes") { sheet3.showSheet(); } else { sheet3.hideSheet(); }
  if (celld == "Yes") { sheet4.showSheet(); } else { sheet4.hideSheet(); }
  if (celle == "Yes") { sheet5.showSheet(); } else { sheet5.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellf == "Yes") { sheet6.showSheet(); } else { sheet6.hideSheet(); }
  if (cellg == "Yes") { sheet7.showSheet(); } else { sheet7.hideSheet(); }
  if (celli == "Yes") { sheet8.showSheet(); } else { sheet8.hideSheet(); }


  // The fucntion for hide/unhide row in 8 s sheet
  var eos = cp.getSheetByName("8 s");
  var cellx = eos.getRange("D13").getValue();
  if ((cellx == "E") || ((cellx == ""))) { eos.hideRows(15); } else { eos.showRows(15); }



  // The fucntion for hide/unhide rows in 1 s 
  var general_info = cp.getSheetByName("0 S");
  var check = general_info.getRange("J9").getValue();
  if (check == "Dir") { sheet1.hideRows(37, 8); } else {
    if ((check == "Par") || (check == "")) {
      sheet1.showRows(37, 8);
    }
  }

// script for toggle
  var toggle = sheet8.getRange("G2");

  for(var i=0;i<50;i++) {
    if( i%2 == 0 ){
      toggle.setFontColor("red");
      toggle.setFontSize(12);
    }
   else{
      toggle.setFontColor("black");
      toggle.setFontSize(10);
    }
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  Utilities.sleep(100);


}
```

The `script for toggle` code block uses a for loop and changes the font color and size to grab attention.

Only the `else` part of the code block works upon edit and then it stops.

Is it because there are other code blocks of hiding/unhiding sheets and hiding/unhiding rows the toggle does not work.

I am not understanding why the cell does not toggle. Please help

Comment: Please provide [mcve] that highlights the current issue.

Comment: In your script, `cp` is not declared. By this, an error occurs at the line of `var sheet1 = cp.getSheetByName("1 s");`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your current script. How about this? And, if `cp` has already been declared elsewhere, at the loop process below `script for toggle`, the cell "G2" of `sheet8` is changed continuously, and the last loop is `toggle.setFontColor("black")` and `toggle.setFontSize(10)`. So, I cannot understand `Only the else part of the code block works upon edit, and then it stops.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: I ma really sorry @Tanaike, i just edited the script and made ```cp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();``` . Now, the toggle loop is not working when an edit happens. its like the loop only executes for one iteration, I want the cell ""G@ of ```sheet8``` toggle its font size and color for all the iterations. What I am struggling at is I dont' know why the loop runs for just one iteration

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand `I want the cell ""G@ of sheet8 toggle its font size and color for all the iterations.`. Especially, I cannot understand `the cell ""G@ of sheet8 toggle`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Apologies from my end, its cell G8. The goal is to toggle the font size and color of the text value which is "Please fill all details in this sheet" in cell G8 in sheet8, This increase and decrease along with change of color will grab the attention of the onlooker

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your goal, from your reply, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your following reply,

> its cell G8. The goal is to toggle the font size and color of the text value which is "Please fill all details in this sheet" in cell G8 in sheet8, This increase and decrease along with change of color will grab the attention of the onlooker

Is your expected result as follows? Please modify your script as follows.

#### From:

```
var toggle = sheet8.getRange("G2");

for(var i=0;i<50;i++) {
  if( i%2 == 0 ){
    toggle.setFontColor("red");
    toggle.setFontSize(12);
  }
 else{
    toggle.setFontColor("black");
    toggle.setFontSize(10);
  }
}
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
Utilities.sleep(100);
```

#### To:

```
var toggle = sheet8.getRange("G8").activate(); // Modified
for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    toggle.setFontColor("red");
    toggle.setFontSize(12);
  } else {
    toggle.setFontColor("black");
    toggle.setFontSize(10);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Modified
  Utilities.sleep(100); // Modified
}
```

Comment: This works amazingly, what was the change, I don't see much change in the code, why does this work? can you please help understand

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `I don't see much change in the code`, the script is surely changed. By putting `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` in the loop, the current situation by the script is reflected in the Spreadsheet. By this, you can see the change in the loop process. And, by `Utilities.sleep(100)`, the wait time is given. If my explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.